# how can i insert data using javascript fetch api

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter

I am trying to get data to form my `view page` using `fetch`

Result:

`var_dump($_POST)` then result show `array(0) {}` mean empty array

```
 function newCustomerAdd(){
  url = "data.php";
  const x = {
      name : "hasan",
      roll : 1
  }
 fetch(url,{
     method : "POST",
     body : JSON.stringify(x),
     headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     },
 }).then(function(response){
     return response.text();
 }).then(function(text){
    console.log(text);
 }).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
 })

 }
```

But `var_dump($_POST)` then result show `array(0) {}` mean empty array

My question how can I get data to from my `view page`

Comment: What was wrong with your previous question on the same topic? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56116734/how-can-insert-data-using-fetch-api

Comment: not get right answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can insert data using fetch api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56116734/how-can-insert-data-using-fetch-api)

Comment: posting the same question again just because you didn't get the answer you expected in the first try is not the way to go. You'll ether have a moderator close this one, or attract the exact same answers from your previous question

Comment: i delete old  question

Comment: `data.php` doesn't look like a valid codeigniter route

Comment: try removing headers

Answer (score 0):

`JavaScript Code`

```
  function newCustomerAdd(){
  url = "data.php";
  let x = {
      name : "hasan",
      roll : 1
  }
 fetch(url,{
     method : "POST",
     body : JSON.stringify(x),
     headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/text'
     },
 }).then(function(response){
     return response.text();
 }).then(function(text){
    console.log(text);
 }).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
  })
 }
```

`PHP code`
 Just get data

```
$content = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
print_r($content);
```